# Facebook Integration and logout url

Tags: facebook

I am confused as to what does the facebook logoutUrl does in the facebook integration?
Does it destroy the current session?
Would session_destroy do the same thing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Facebook Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/):

> This method returns a URL that, when clicked by the user, will log
>   them out of their Facebook session and then redirect them back to your
>   application.

It will also invalidate the user access token so that you will no longer be able to call any graph APIs against that user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I more specifically wanted to know whether the session is destroyed in general, i.e. is the logout url a superset of php's session_destroy?

Answer (score 2):

When we are integrating facebook, on success of the login of a user, we need to create login session by using the user details provided from facebook and the logout is actually our application logout, not the facebook logout.

Answer (score 0):

when we loggin, we get access token , after we logout , access token also get destroyed.
so we have to logout  to maintain session management in our application.